# Displaying camera in custom frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

I'm trying to load the camera into a custom `CGRect`, but I'm not able to do so as it appears the view is bound by the camera aspect. This is the code I'm using:

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if (videoDevice)
{
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:videoDevice error:&error];
    if (!error)
    {
        if ([session canAddInput:videoInput])
        {
            [session addInput:videoInput];
            AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
            previewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
            CGFloat x = self.view.bounds.origin.x;
            CGFloat y = self.view.bounds.origin.y;
            CGFloat width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
            CGFloat height = 206;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
            previewLayer.frame = newFrame;
            [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
            [session startRunning];
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the frame that the app is currently displaying:**

[image]

**But I need it to be framed like this:**

[image]

I can't figure out how to "unlock" the camera frame or adjust the aspect. Is my desired result possible without lowering image quality, and if so - how?

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: @metronic Hey, thanks for your answer. I haven't been able just yet - got a little late last night and I haven't got a lightning cable with me at school. I'll try asap I get home, which is about 2-3 hours from now. I'll report back right away after trying

Comment: @metronic yup, that fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line at the end of your code:

```
previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```